# Node attempting to read file before synchronous write finishes

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am trying to make my program such that it will attempt to read a config file, and if the config file doesn't exist, the program will generate a new config file from `config.example.js` and then require the newly generated file.  However, I am running into an issue - even with using `fs.writeFileSync()`, it appears that Node is running `config = require('config.js');` before the "synchronous" write finishes, as it crashes with `Cannot find module './config.js'`.

Here is the code in question:

```
var config;
//Create new config file if one not found
try {
    config = require('./config.js');
} catch (e){
    fs.writeFileSync('./config.js', fs.readFileSync('./config.js.example'));
    console.log("New config file config.js created");
    config = require('./config.js');  //Line it crashes on
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to do some kind of a callback.  I'm not sure, but I'm very interested in the correct answer =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the way caching works with require. Because the first one failed, so will the second one until the event loop clears. Try it this way instead.

```
if (fs.existsSync('/config.js')) {
    config = require('./config');
} else {
    fs.writeFileSync('./config.js', fs.readFileSync('./config.js.example'));
    config = require('./config');
}
```

Comment: This fixed it.  Thanks!